# adding a specific user to see something on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, roles

I have a simple rails app where i have divided users into roles **Sellers** and **Customers** with id 1 and 2 respectively. Now i want **customers** to see something different then **sellers** on the index page and for that I had tried this but nothing happened.

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <% if role_id == 1 %>
            <%= link_to "Add a new Shipment", new_shipment_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
        <% else %>
            <% @shipments.each do |shipment| %>
        <div class="shipment">
        <h3><strong><%= shipment.user.full_name%></strong></h3>
        <h5><strong>DESCRIPTION: </strong><%= shipment.description %></h5>
         <div class="thumbnail">
        <td><%= image_tag shipment.image.url(:medium)%></td>
          <div class="meta">
            <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(shipment.created_at) + " ago" %> |
            <%= link_to "show", shipment %>
            <span class="admin"> 
              | <%= link_to "Edit", edit_shipment_path(shipment) %> |
              <%= link_to "Delete", shipment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Hey! Are you sure! You wanna delete this shipment??"} %>
          </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
</div>
        <% end %>
```

*My seeds.rb*

```
['seller', 'customer'].each do |role|
  Role.find_or_create_by({name: role})
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was really a heck but as i was not getting help from anywhere
I posted one more question on this issue on stackoverflow 
And then this humble guy @Rich peck helped me out of this.

[Here's the link to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665930/adding-a-specific-roles-to-user-to-see-something-on-the-page/32668137#32668137)

Comment: Please post the content of the link so when people view this question they can see the solution. Sometimes questions/answers get deleted and links die. Also, please keep answers only related to the answer and not about the experience of finding an answer. This is important for keeping StackOverflow a high quality site. I'll upvote you once you make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have have TWO typos. It's `<% end %>` instead of `<% end -%>`, and it's `<% if role_id == "1" %>`. Notice the `-` and `=` instead of `%` and `==`.

It's also important to make sure you keep everything nested properly because your nesting is completely off. Your `div` is ended in the middle of an if-else block, and you prematurely `end` your if-else block. It should be like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-right">
    <% if role_id == 1 %>
        <%= link_to "Add a new Shipment", new_shipment_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "something else", class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I believe `find_or_create_by` is deprecated. Instead use `first_or_create`.

```
['seller', 'customer'].each do |role|
    Role.where(name: role).first_or_create
end
```

Another quick couple comments:

It's better style to have a role variable in the controller for the seller/customer e.g. `user_role`. This is better because now instead of comparing the ID, you compare the name. This way you can do `<% if user_role.name == "seller" %>`.

If you insist on doing it by `id` instead of name, then you should treat the `id` as an integer e.g. `<% if role_id == 1 %>`

EDIT: I modified my nesting example to use `== 1` instead of `= '1'`, and I fixed a typo.

Comment: thank for the help @Dbz your solution worked but not fully. Am getting what i wanted but for both the role id's 1 and 2. i have updated my question with the <% else %> statement please have a look

Comment: You did not fix the `<% if role_id = "1" %>` typo, and you did not fix the nesting issues. If you fix those issues, then you will likely fix all of your problems. At the moment, there are serious issues with how you are nesting your ERB/HTML, and you are relying on the web browser to make assumptions and fix it for you which will cause browser specific bugs.

Comment: A good start would be to properly indent your ERB/HTML. If you're still having issues, please update your question with properly spaced/indented ERB/HTML.

Comment: i had updated the question with my old index page. i had tried your solution with what you have said but as i said now am getting the same page for both the customers and sellers

Comment: I believe the reason is because even though you have all the correct ruby code, it is placed in the HTML incorrectly. You must make sure opening and closing brackets (`<a></a>`) and if-else blocks are properly contained inside all sets of opening and closing brackets (`<a>if-else</a>end` would be wrong.). Try pasting your entire page [here](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/10au/indent.html) and check out how your code looks after it tries to re-indent for you.

Comment: now it's giving an error undefined local variable or method `role_id' for

Comment: It should be `@role_id`, and you will need that variable in the controller.

Comment: @Denialsmith did this answer your question?

Comment: Can you post the solution so that other people who run into the same problem as you can see the answer?