# adding a specific roles to user to see something on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, roles

although i had this question before but did not get anything useful and am stuck. Ok my app is a simple ebay clone, where i had divided users into roles buyers and sellers with role id 1 and 2. When anyone sign up or login they are transferred to the index page of the app, Now i want buyers to see something different then sellers on the index page and for that I had tried the if and else method but nothing happened. Is am doing anything wrong?
I there any other way to get on this.

**My Index.html.erb file**

```
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <% if role_id == 1 %>
            <%= link_to "Add a new Product", new_product_path, class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <% @products.each do |productt| %>
    <div class="product">
    <h4><strong><font style="text-transform: capitalize;"><%= shipment.user.full_name%></strong></h4></font>
    <h5><strong>DESCRIPTION: </strong><%= product.description %></h5>
     <div class="thumbnail">
    <td><%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium)%></td>
      <div class="meta">
        <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(product.created_at) + " ago" %>
        <span class="admin"> 
          | <%= link_to "Show Details", product %>
       </span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and

**My seeds.rb**

```
['buyers', 'sellers'].each do |role|
    Role.where(name: role).first_or_create
end
```

Comment: How do you identify whether the use is a buyer or a seller? You'd need to associate each user with roles to identify whether the user is a buyer or a seller.

Comment: hey @nayiaw i am new to rails can you please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study a little bit more about system structure. Specifically, you're asking how to send a buyer/seller to different pages (which indicates a major system divide), whereas I think you're really asking about [*authorization*](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/authorization).

> - *Authorization* = giving a user permission to do something
> - *Authentication* = are they a user at all?

I think you should have a base level user (no "roles"), with the ability to assign specific authorization ability to each user.

This will basically make every user a *buyer*, except for ones who have *permission* to sell. This way, you can assign a "level" to your users, allowing them actions if they have that level in their dataset.

--

I would have it set up like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | username | password | role_id | etc
   belongs_to :role
   def has_role? test_role
       role.id == test_role
   end
end

#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | name | description | etc
   has_many :users
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
<%= link_to "Add a new Product", new_product_path, class: "btn btn-success" if current_user.has_role? "1" %>
```

This will give you the ability to add a series of roles to your `Role` model, allocating one to each user. This will define the amount of functionality that user will have access to (IE they can only sell if they are at level "2" etc).